# how to flush macports installation queue?

Tags: macports

I wanted to install git with macports - it failed. ok. So I went with dmg - succeeded.

However, now I cannot remove git from some install queue and if I want install anything it still fetches git install command (which is failing btw).

so.. "sudo port install htop" still invokes "sudo port install git-core"

how to fix it?

Comment: You should edit your question to include more of the error messages you are getting. The stuff in your comment to Nerdling's answer is a start, but it is not much to go on—it indicates that libexpat is not being found by the linker, maybe try rebuilding the expat port `port upgrade --force expat`?

Answer (score 2):

`htop` uses a git repo.  You have to install `git-core` first.  Try this first:

> sudo port clean git-core

Comment: did that.
also with selfupdate before.
didn't know about git dependency, so just forget theory with install queue ;)
this is error output: 

Command output:       _lock_remote in http-push.o
      _main in http-push.o
  "_XML_GetErrorCode", referenced from:
      _remote_ls in http-push.o
      _lock_remote in http-push.o
  
 ... similar  

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [git-http-push] Error 1